# Enter ComboBox value using AutoIt C# Wrapper

Tags: c#, winforms, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am using AutoIt to run automated tests on a C# WinForms application. Previously, using AutoIt code I was able to select a ComboBox value like this:

```
_GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString($hCalendarYearComboBox, $oProject.calendarYear)
```

However, I am now trying to write the same code using the AutoIt C# wrapper and I cannot achieve it. First and foremost I do not see any way of using the `GUICtrlComboBox` methods. I tried, as an alternative, to use the [`ControlCommand`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlCommand.htm) function like this:

```
_autoit.ControlCommand("Main Window Text", "", "[NAME:calendarYearComboBox]", "2015 Calendar Year");
```

This does not set the proper ComboBox text. I have also tried by getting the handle first:

```
var calYearHandle = _autoit.ControlGetHandle("Main Window Text", "", "[NAME:calendarYearComboBox]");
_autoit.ControlCommand("Main Window Text", "", calYearHandle, "2015 Calendar Year");
```

I have searched the AutoIt forums which are usually pretty helpful, but I can't find anything about setting ComboBox values using the C# wrapper. Is there any way I can use the `_GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString` method using the C# wrapper, and if not is there anything wrong with my ControlCommand statement?